# Next.js 13 - ssr with differnet packages

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, i18next, chakra-ui, next.js13

Started a new Next.js 13 and chakra-ui app.
I discovered that every component of chakra has to be rendered on the client, so I have to add "use client" directive.

Then it happened again with i18next, so I can translate only on the client.

So basically, I can't use ssr anywhere on my app. all my basic building blocks has to be rendered on the client.

With next-12 I used chakra and i18next and still could use ssr with getServerSideProps or getStaticProps, even if I had an event interaction.

Is there something I'm missing here?